# Как добавить файл-Github

Tags: git, github

Как добавить файл в репозиторий на Github?
 С помощью обучающей статьи (https://guides.github.com/activities/hello-world/) получилось создать README.md,но о  том,как добавить свой файл там ничего не сказано.

Comment: Думаю вам нужно в принципе изучить [основы git](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/Введение-Основы-Git)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Склонируйте удаленный репозиторий в вашу локальную папку, используя команду [clone](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone)

```
git clone git://github.com/schacon/grit.git
```

Либо еще вариант

1. Создайте ваш локальный репозиторий, вызовите в каталоге "проекта" команду `git init`
2. Добавьте файлы в репозиторий командой `git add <folder>(или <file>)`(например, `git add .` - добавит рекурсивно все файлы в текущем каталоге в локальный репозиторий)
3. Сделайте ваш первый локальный коммит в репозиторий `git commit -m "First commit"`
4. Добавляем локальному репозиторию ссылку на удаленный репозиторий *github*   `git remote add origin https://github.com/user/repo.git`
5. Теперь можно сделать команду `push` в удаленный репозиторий `git push origin master`
   ,тем самым отправив вашу локальную ветку master на сервер origin(на *github* репозиторий). Теперь вы можете видеть добавленные файлы на *github*.

Если у вас имеется уже локальный репозиторий, и вы хотите его залить на *github*, то выполните все пункты, начиная с 4. После этого ваш локальный репозиторий будет располагаться на сервере github.

Comment: Вы уверены что git clone не будет лучше, если удалённый репозиторий не пустой?

Comment: да, и в вашем случае push не пройдёт, т. к. нужен мердж

Comment: да, конечно, можно использовать простой `clone`. А на счет `push` не пройдет, не знаю, сколько использую, всегда проходит без проблем.

Comment: «`git add . ` - добавит все файлы в текущей каталоге в локальный репозиторий» — а вот и нет )) Почти верно, но есть неточность.

Comment: @Nick, уточните пожалуйста.

Comment: Про рекурсию дополнение верное, и про текущий каталог тоже верно. Но стоит уточнить, что файлы добавляются в индекс. Строго говоря, он тоже в репозитории находится, но фраза может ввести новичка в заблуждение.

Comment: @Nick, спасибо за замечание, подправил.